# Can I predict with less number of attributes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have an ML model that predicts a target attribute `y` with `5` other attributes namely `Age`, `Sex`, `Satisfaction`, `Height` and `weight`

Let's say that I have a new dataset **but it is short `Age`** so it has only `4` attributes namely `Sex`, `Satisfaction`, `Height` and `weight`

So that new dataset I am going to predict has lost one column (attribute) which is `Age`

Is it still possible to predict the target attribute 'y`?

Note: - I have my model exported with the `pickel` python library and trying to predict the new dataset as folllow:

```
model=pickle.load(open('gaussian.pkl','rb'))
print(model.predict(inputs)) # ----------------> inputs which has now only 4 attributes
```

And this gives an error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,4) (5,)

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some models that can handle NaN (empty) values, life XGBOOST, and some models that can't. 
Your best option here will be to re-train a model with only the 4 features. 
If you can't you can give multiple values to "age" (like 2-99), predict y each time, and take the average of those predictions. 
Again, you will really be better to re-train your model on the features without age if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to predict y using fewer Xs. You need more data to train your model. 
Keep in mind that 1st example in machine learning is to predict y using just one x.